# soap curl request works but response doesnt

Tags: php, xml, soap, curl, response

I am supposed to receive a variable called "D" after server receives the string I sent. How do I get it to receive the server responses message?

```
$soapme = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($soapme, CURLOPT_URL,            $url );   
curl_setopt($soapme, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); 
curl_setopt($soapme, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10); 
curl_setopt($soapme, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($soapme, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($soapme, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($soapme, CURLOPT_POST,           true ); 
curl_setopt($soapme, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,    $post_string); 
curl_setopt($soapme, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length: '.strlen($post_string) )); 
curl_setopt($soapme, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($soapme, curlOPT_VERBOSE, 1); 
curl_exec($soapme);
```

I notice I get a 1 as a result when I do not use ReturnTransfers. What does this 1 mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = curl_exec($soapme);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Its blank. The server admin (separate company) says he received my sent message, but I still get a blank response.

Comment: try running curl from the command line to see what you get back: `curl -v -D "your_post_string" http://endpoint`

Comment: is there a curl.exe for windows? I am not on linux

Comment: Looks like there is. I haven't tried it though: http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?CURL_7.21.7 Any web proxy tool like [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/download/) is also good for working with web services. Otherwise you'll need to talk to the 3rd party and find out why the response is empty.

Comment: I notice I get a 1 as a result when I do not use ReturnTransfers. What does this 1 mean?

Comment: this means true, as in successful. you'll need to have returntransfer on if you want to receive data back